# Spark window functions: first match in window

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I'm trying to extend the results of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48997461/creating-a-unique-grouping-key-from-column-wise-runs-in-a-spark-dataframe), but haven't been able to figure out how to achieve my new goal.

Before, I wanted to key on either a flag match or a string match. Now, I want to create a unique grouping key from a run starting with either a flag being `true` or the first string match preceding a run of `true` flag values.

Here's some example data:

```
val msgList = List("b", "f")

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("a", false), ("b", false), ("c", false), ("b", false), ("c", true), ("d", false), ("e", true), ("f", true), ("g", false)))
              .toDF("message", "flag")
              .withColumn("index", monotonically_increasing_id)

df.show

+-------+-----+-----+
|message| flag|index|
+-------+-----+-----+
|      a|false|    0|
|      b|false|    1|
|      c|false|    2|
|      b|false|    3|
|      c| true|    4|
|      d|false|    5|
|      e| true|    6|
|      f| true|    7|
|      g|false|    8|
+-------+-----+-----+
```

The desired output is something equivalent to either of `key1` or `key2`:

```
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|message| flag|index| key1| key2|
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|      a|false|    0|    0| null|
|      b|false|    1|    1|    1|
|      c|false|    2|    1|    1|
|      b|false|    3|    1|    1|
|      c| true|    4|    1|    1|
|      d|false|    5|    2| null|
|      e| true|    6|    3|    2|
|      f| true|    7|    3|    2|
|      g|false|    8|    4| null|
+-------+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

From the answer to my previous question, I already have a precursor:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val checkMsg = udf { (s: String) => s != null && msgList.exists(s.contains(_)) }

val df2 = df.withColumn("message_match", checkMsg($"message"))
            .withColumn("match_or_flag", when($"message_match" || $"flag", 1).otherwise(0))
            .withColumn("lead", lead("match_or_flag", -1, 1).over(Window.orderBy("index")))
            .withColumn("switched", when($"match_or_flag" =!= $"lead", $"index"))
            .withColumn("base_key", last("switched", ignoreNulls = true).over(Window.orderBy("index").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)))

df2.show

+-------+-----+-----+-------------+-------------+----+--------+--------+
|message| flag|index|message_match|match_or_flag|lead|switched|base_key|
+-------+-----+-----+-------------+-------------+----+--------+--------+
|      a|false|    0|        false|            0|   1|       0|       0|
|      b|false|    1|         true|            1|   0|       1|       1|
|      c|false|    2|        false|            0|   1|       2|       2|
|      b|false|    3|         true|            1|   0|       3|       3|
|      c| true|    4|        false|            1|   1|    null|       3|
|      d|false|    5|        false|            0|   1|       5|       5|
|      e| true|    6|        false|            1|   0|       6|       6|
|      f| true|    7|         true|            1|   1|    null|       6|
|      g|false|    8|        false|            0|   1|       8|       8|
+-------+-----+-----+-------------+-------------+----+--------+--------+
```

`base_key` here is somewhat close to `key1` above, but assigns separate keys to rows 1 and rows 3-4. I want rows 1-4 to get a single key based on the fact that row 1 contains the first `msgList` match within or preceding a run of `flag` = `true`.

Looking at the [Spark window function API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec), it looks like there might be some way to use `rangeBetween` to accomplish this as of Spark 2.3.0, but the docs are bare enough that I haven't been able to figure out how to make it work.

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: I was able to use another column in the data to generate a different `base_key`, then check for `message` matches within each of those groups, which worked. I didn't actually solve the problem posed in the question.